# Help me understand how the FCI cluster quorum works when 2 nodes are remaining of a 2 node + 1 file share cluster?

Tags: sql-server, clustering, sql-server-2019

Link: https://learnsqlserverhadr.com/so-you-think-your-sql-server-availability-group-is-really-highly-available/

The example given is that - there are 2 nodes and 1 file share. The author says file share goes down, and the cluster remains active because it has 2/3 votes.

At this point they say the following about Dynamic quorum (when 2 nodes are remaining):

> The good thing is that they were on Windows Server 2012. This version
> of Windows Server introduced the concept of dynamic quorum and is
> enabled, by default.  The WSFC manages the vote assignments to the
> nodes depending on their state. If the node is taken offline –
> rebooted, powered down, disconnected from the network, etc. – it’s
> vote is also removed from the cluster. **It’s the reason why the AG went
> offline when the cluster node was rebooted.**

I'm trying to understand why did the AG (cluster) go offline?

This documentation says that (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/hci/concepts/quorum#two-nodes-without-a-witness):

> One node's vote is zeroed, so the majority vote is determined out of a
> total of 1 vote. If the non-voting node goes down unexpectedly, the
> survivor has 1/1 and the cluster survives. If the voting node goes
> down unexpectedly, the survivor has 0/1 and the cluster goes down. If
> the voting node is gracefully powered down, the vote is transferred to
> the other node, and the cluster survives. This is why it's critical to
> configure a witness.

Specifically it says: If the voting node is gracefully powered down, the vote is transferred to the other node, and the cluster survives.

And further down it says:

> Whenever surviving nodes successfully verify they are the majority,
> the definition of majority is updated to be among just the survivors.
> This allows the cluster to lose one node, then another, then another,
> and so forth. This concept of the total number of votes adapting after
> successive failures is known as Dynamic quorum.

My question assuming in the 2 node + 1 fileshare setup, say the file share goes down, then:

1. Assuming node1 is set to 0 (by dynamic quorum), then if I shutdown node2 then wouldn't have any effect on the cluster. (Because dynamic quorum will switch over the voting power to node1)? Quorum>0.5
2. Assuming node1 is set to 0 (by dynamic quorum), If node1 goes down then also the cluster will remain alive since quorum > 0.5
3. Assuming node2 is set to 0 (by dynamic quorum), and node2 is shutdown then cluster will remain alive as quorum >0.5
4. Assuming node2 is set to 0 (by dynamic quorum), then if I shutdown node1 also the cluster will remain online since vote will switch to node2 and quorum>0.5
5. Why did the author's cluster go down?

Comment: Seriously "why did the AG (cluster) go offline?" The cluster had 3 nodes, then the 3rd (fileshare) was down, then the 2nd node was rebooted. Only 1 node left and you wonder why the AG went offline?

Comment: Please help me understand because the dynamic quorum is supposed to handle this. When the file share goes down, that means we are left we 2/3 and the cluster is working. Now we have 2 nodes, so the dynamic quorum will 0 one of the nodes so effectively we need votes > 1/2 (0.5). So it is sufficient that 1 node survives to keep the cluster alive. So again my question is when the 2nd node was rebooted we still have quorum (1>0.5) so why did cluster go offline?

Comment: The threshold is 1.5 and doesn't change. When the fileshare went down, you had 2 >1.5 (so AG online). When the 2nd node went down, you had 1 < 1.5 (so AG offline).

Comment: See this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/hci/concepts/quorum#two-nodes-without-a-witness - it explains what happens when only 2 nodes are remaining. And further down it says: `Whenever surviving nodes successfully verify they are the majority, the definition of majority is updated to be among just the survivors. This allows the cluster to lose one node, then another, then another, and so forth. This concept of the total number of votes adapting after successive failures is known as Dynamic quorum.`

Comment: About what happens with 2 nodes cluster (from the same link): `One node's vote is zeroed, so the majority vote is determined out of a total of 1 vote. If the non-voting node goes down unexpectedly, the survivor has 1/1 and the cluster survives. If the voting node goes down unexpectedly, the survivor has 0/1 and the cluster goes down. If the voting node is gracefully powered down, the vote is transferred to the other node, and the cluster survives. This is why it's critical to configure a witness.`

Comment: These excerpts should be on the question. The link you added initially does not have this info, actually it has no info about dynamic quorum. It doesn't even clearly specify what mode/settings the AG was configured with when the incident happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Specifically it says: If the voting node is gracefully powered down, the vote is transferred to the other node, and the cluster survives.

In his example he's explaining that dynamic witness and dynamic quorum help with cluster availability. Whether or not the dynamic weight of a node changes depends on the current configuration and current status of the cluster, along with some random data such as node id.

> Assuming node1 is set to 0, then if I shutdown node2 then wouldn't have any effect on the cluster.

If you've set the node weight of node1 to 0, then it doesn't have a vote, ever. If this is a 2 node cluster as your question suggests, then reboot node 2, the cluster would be down.

If you're talking about dynamic quorum kicking in, then in the 2-node cluster with witness case, the vote will not be removed dynamically. It'll keep the cluster at 3 votes, since by requirement dynamic witness will be set to a vote if the number of node votes is even (which it is in a 2-node cluster). Changing the votes does nothing to help availability of the cluster.

Either way, with a witness that is available, losing one node will not cause availability loss.

> Assuming node2 is set to 0, then if I shutdown node1 then does the cluster immediately switch the vote to the node1 thereby keeping cluster alive or does it take down the cluster and then bring it backup after switching the vote to node1?

Since as I stated above, the votes will not be changed dynamically in a 2-node setup, the only way for node 2 to not have a vote is that it was manually set. In that case, the cluster would be down.  Otherwise, as I explained previously, the node would have a vote and the cluster would stay up.

> Why did the author's cluster go down?

Because Edwin was specifically pointing out the dynamic witness and dynamic quorum changes made in WS2012R2 and above and demonstrated this by using WS2012 which did not have all of the items implemented (and also mentions 2008R2 which had *neither* of the implementations).

Comment: `Assuming node1 is set to 0, then if I shutdown node2 then wouldn't have any effect on the cluster.` by IS SET TO 0 I meant to say it is set to 0 by the dynamic quorum mechanism. In that case the cluster wouldnt go down. Yes?

Comment: `If you're talking about dynamic quorum kicking in, then in the 2-node cluster with witness case, the vote will not be removed dynamically. It'll keep the cluster at 3 votes, since by requirement dynamic witness will be set to a vote if the number of node votes is even (which it is in a 2-node cluster). Changing the votes does nothing to help availability of the cluster.` if the witness goes down then dynamic quorum will classify this cluster as a 2 node cluster and randomly assign 1 vote to 1 of nodes. So quorum >0.5 is needed for cluster to remain alive. Yes?

Comment: > by IS SET TO 0 I meant to say it is set to 0 by the dynamic quorum mechanism.
As I stated in my answer, please read it, dynamic quorum won't set it to 0.

Comment: >if the witness goes down then dynamic quorum will classify this cluster as a 2 node cluster and randomly assign 1 vote to 1 of nodes.

No, it won't.

Comment: Once the file share goes down, then we have 2 nodes remaining. Now if you apply the following msdn logic then it comes across to me as though the quorum > 1 (2*1/2) - `Whenever surviving nodes successfully verify they are the majority, the definition of majority is updated to be among just the survivors. This allows the cluster to lose one node, then another, then another, and so forth. This concept of the total number of votes adapting after successive failures is known as Dynamic quorum.`

Comment: You are free to try it yourself rather than constantly quoting items assuming they are the truth and understanding how it works yourself. If you don't believe me as I'm another random person on the internet, please try it yourself. I've answered the questions, and the new questions are the old questions in different form.

Comment: This video covers what you are saying (at around 18:00): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WZqVdJrEFX8

Comment: your response to `Why did the author's cluster go down?` says `WS2012 which did not have all of the items implemented` - so in WS2019 would things behave differently? If so then what would be the difference please?

Comment: The differences are documented. This question is answered.

Comment: Where can I get differences?

Comment: learn.microsoft.com look at what's new in windows server version.

Comment: My point is - whether or not it is ws 2012 or 2019, when you have 2 node + 1 file share in wsfc, then if the file share goes down, and then 1 node goes down, then the cluster will go offline.

Comment: No, it depends on the timeline and order of how those occur.

Comment: Please can you elaborate